# Open a new window after Finish Button has been clicked on Qwizard : Pyqt5

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qwizard

I want to have the finish button on my QWizard do something else besides exit the page. I need to connect it to a function that calls another window. In other words, I need to view and add functionality to the Finish Button of the Qwizard page. Does anyone know how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its mostly the same you are already used to do in PyQt. The differences are in how to find the Finish button entity. Here is a working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class IntroPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(IntroPage, self).__init__(parent)

class LastPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LastPage, self).__init__(parent)

class MyWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWizard, self).__init__(parent)

        self.introPage = IntroPage()
        self.lastPage = LastPage()
        self.setPage(0, self.introPage)
        self.setPage(1, self.lastPage)

        # This is the code you need
        self.button(QtWidgets.QWizard.FinishButton).clicked.connect(self._doSomething)

    def _doSomething(self):
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText("Yep, its connected.")
        msgBox.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MyWizard()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Notice how I used this command: `self.button(QtWidgets.QWizard.FinishButton)` to specifically point to the finish button. The rest is just build your own method to do whatever you need. In my example I connected to `def _doSomething(self)` and launched a very simple QMessageBox.

Comment: High, this works perfectly on both MacOSX and Windows. However if wizard calls a QWidget instead of QMessageBox, the form appears and stays on MacOSX but quickly disappears on Windows. Do you know why that may be?

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.qt.io/topic/44065/how-to-catch-finish-button-pressed-signal-in-qwizard/6

I think here is answer how to catch finish button press event.
I have never worked with pyqt5 but I think signal and slot is the same as in c++.

Answer (score 0):

When Your Press on your QPushbutton You Have QWizard Object?

if yes:

use SIGNAL and SLOT!

I do not know how it looks like in Python, but c++ like this:

connect(my_button, SIGNAL(clicked(), your_qwizard_object, SLOT(your_qwizard_slot()));

https://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide

Comment: I need it to open a QtWidget object. Plus, I need the built in Finish button on the conclusion page to perform this function and close the wizard

Comment: Thanks. I will have to make sense of this in python though. I have very little knowledge of C++. In words, must I use signal slot to over ride the default finish button function??

Comment: i think yes.
https://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide
read this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void MainWindow::on_btnCreateWizard_clicked() { 
    MyWizardForm* dlg = new MyWizardForm(this); 
    connect(dlg, SIGNAL(_finished()), this, SLOT(slot_show_me()));
    this->hide();
    dlg.exec(); 
} 

void MainWindow::slot_show_me() { 
    this->show();
} 

void MyWizardForm::on_btnClose_Clicked() { 
    emit _finished();
    this->reject();
}
```

Comment: Is this a mainWindow calling a wizardpage? how about the opposite. I have a fuctioning mainwindow form that works well independently. How ever when its called from qwizard it shows but crashes when you click a button from it.